# Iptables redirection to main proxy after filter on local proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, linux-networking, zentyal

I manage a subnet linked to an Institutional network (IN). Internet access from my subnet is through a proxy with credentials (they are not related to the users of my domain) in the IN. I need to apply several filters that are not implemented by that proxy. For that purpose I use squid on my local network with a non-transparent proxy. The problem is that after filtering with squid, I need to redirect to the IN proxy. I implement an iptables DNAT in PREROUTING and that way my clients are authenticated and navigate correctly. The issue is that when I change the destination address of the packets they don't go through my firewall .

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.2.12.100:3128
```

I need something like this

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.2.12.100:3128
```

Is it correct when I assume that the normal route of packets in iptables directed to my proxy is ...,INPUT, LOCAL PROCESSES(run squid), OUTPUT,...? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can set up squid to use a other proxy for the next hop, did you consider it?

Comment: Not really. I didn't know that squid has that functionality. It is similar to proxychains?

Comment: similar said to keep it simple, yes